# How can I center flexbox items that are inside of a row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to centre the columns inside of a row but they won't centre. I've already tried changing the code multiple times but I can't seem to find the error. Already tried to `justify-content:center` and `align-items:center` in both "services" and "section-3" classes and it doesn't work. I'm also not able to centre the "What I do" text which is part of the top row.

What it looks like now:

[image]

```
          <div class="what-i-do">
            <h3>WHAT I DO</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row services">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="first-column">
                <h3 class="services-title">
                  Content <br />
                  Creation
                </h3>
                <div class="services-text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                  ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                  eu.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="second-column">
                <h3 class="services-title">
                  Strategy <br />
                  Session
                </h3>
                <div class="services-text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                  ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                  eu.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="third-column">
                <h3 class="services-title">Branding</h3>
                <div class="services-text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                  ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                  eu.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 100px;
}
.section-3 {
  background-color: hsla(7, 56%, 85%, 0.746);
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.what-i-do {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding: 100px 0px 200px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;

}

.services {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.services-title {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.first-column {
  width: 250px;
}

.second-column {
  width: 250px;
}

.third-column {
  width: 250px;
}

.services-text {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: I ran your snippets in a codepen and it centered for me immediately.
I suspect you have what-i-do in a column since it looks to be dead center of that far left column positionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `display: flex` rule anywhere. Start with that, then remove your column widths as they defeat the purpose of a flex layout.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.services {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.services-title {
    font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
}

.services-text {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.8;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="row services">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="first-column">
            <h3 class="services-title">
                Content <br />
                Creation
            </h3>
            
            <div class="services-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <div class="second-column">
            <h3 class="services-title">
                Strategy <br />
                Session
            </h3>
            <div class="services-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <div class="third-column">
            <h3 class="services-title">Branding</h3>
            <div class="services-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in row-services { display: flex; justify-content (try items also): center;}

Hard to tell where everything goes but try that.

Comment: Please format this for readability. It's not clear what's code and what's descriptive text.

Answer (score 0):

Both `align-items:center` and `justify-items:center` work in CSS grid. Your issue is likely with other CSS affecting the height/width of the grid, or the placement of the `display:grid` style rule itself:

```css
html, body{height: 100%}

.grid{
    height: 60%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: salmon;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```